# How can I find out if all my hard drives are mounted (Ubuntu Server)?

Tags: mount, disk

I had one hard disk to start with. On that hard disk I installed Ubuntu server. Today I added 2 other hard drives to the system. But I am not sure if the server software mounts the disks. How can I find that out?

Edit: I found the drives with `sudo fdisk -l`. Now I think I can access/mount the drives.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the output of `sudo fdisk -l` to your question?

Comment: @Mitch: Could you please add that comment as an answer, as it solved the issue? Then, Tim can accept it and the edit from the question can be deleted.

Answer (score 6):

Once you physically install the drives in the system, and made sure that they are recognized by your computer's BIOS, boot the computer up, and see if Ubuntu can see the drives. To do that, open up the terminal,  just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Once you see the drives listed, go ahead and create your partitions from terminal using the [fdisk](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/fdisk_partitioning.html) command, [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/), or Disk Utility.